# How to generate QR code in visual studio 2008,asp.net web application using .net 3.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008, qr-code

I want to generate QR code for an asp.net web application using vs2008 and .NET 3.5, I can do that in vs 2012 as it supports library package manager from where I can add the required package, but I don't know how to do that in vs2008.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [QRCoder](http://en.code-bude.net/2013/10/17/qrcoder-an-open-source-qr-code-generator-implementation-in-csharp/), download `.dll`  add to Your project and code [Here is sample tutorial how use it](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-generate-and-display-QR-code-Image-in-ASPNet.aspx)

```
  string code = txtCode.Text;
QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
QRCodeGenerator.QRCode qrCode = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(code, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
imgBarCode.Height = 150;
imgBarCode.Width = 150;
using (Bitmap bitMap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20))
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
        imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
    }
    plBarCode.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
}
```

Comment: hi, I downloaded the QRCoder.dill and pasted it in bin folder, on running I am getting following error
Could not load file or assembly 'QRCoder' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Comment: @steave Either load the source code from Github and compile QRCoder against .NET 3.5 yourself - or use the new Nuget package (1.2.5), which contains also a .NET 3.5 version.